# Kafka does not release the thread, if it does not find topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I noticed that if there are no topic that producer produces messages in, because kafka does not release the thread we can not get response to my http request.

Is there a way to configure Kafka that if we get `UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION` ignore it and do not try to send message.

I see that the below error is being stacked.

```
 [Producer clientId=session-service-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 28 : {*****.session-service.test.v1=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
```

Although I catch any exceptions it breaks the flow.

```
try {
            ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, SessionEvent>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, sessionEvent);
            future.addCallback(sessionEvent.getFutureCallback());
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error("Error", e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that although it was async method, my application was not configured for async methods.

So it was executing the method sync. But I did not throw any exceptions.. So Kafka was still trying to send the message to the invalid topic.